# Uploading file from Blazor Server app to SharePoint Online library

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, server, blazor

I have a Blazor Server app that has a requirement to be able to allow a user to select a file from their local filesystem and upload it into a SharePoint Online library.
I'm utilizing the PnP.Core package for SharePoint functionality.

The app displays a file selection dialog that allows the user to select a specific file.  When I try and add the file to the SPO library, I'm getting a 401 error.  I understand why this would happen but what I can't figure out is how to properly add the file.

The pertinent snippet of code is here:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Upload file from local file system to SPO library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileToUpload">File selected by user</param>
    /// <param name="pnpContextFactory">PnP Context Factory</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAttachment(IBrowserFile fileToUpload, PnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory)
    {
        // Create new PnPContext from factory
        using (var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith"))
        {
            // target location on SPO
            string documentUrl = $"{context.Uri.PathAndQuery}/Documents/PQI";
            
            // get folder object from PnPContext
            var folder = await context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrlAsync(documentUrl);
            if (folder != null)
            {
                // Open a stream (for testing, this would normally be combined in the next line
                Stream s = fileToUpload.OpenReadStream();
                // Upload the file
                // This is where the 401 error is thrown
                await folder.Files.AddAsync(fileToUpload.Name, s);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I'm fairly confident that the error is due to browser security so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question.  The issue was actually not a 401 issue.
I needed to copy the file selected by the user into a memorystream.  Once I did that I was able to get the upload to work.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Upload file from local file system to SPO library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileToUpload">File selected by user</param>
    /// <param name="pnpContextFactory">PnP Context Factory</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAttachment(IBrowserFile fileToUpload, PnPContextFactory pnpContextFactory)
    {
        // Create new PnPContext from factory
        using (var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith"))
        {
            // target location on SPO
            string documentUrl = $"{context.Uri.PathAndQuery}/Documents/PQI";
            
            // get folder object from PnPContext
            var folder = await context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrlAsync(documentUrl);
            if (folder != null)
            {
                **MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                // Open a stream (for testing, this would normally be combined in the next line
                await fileToUpload.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);**
                // Upload the file
                // This is where the 401 error is thrown
                await folder.Files.AddAsync(fileToUpload.Name, ms);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```